# What's the point of `split` inside `align`?

Tags: align, environments, split

I sometimes see people using the `split` environment inside the `align` environment. What is gained by this? After all, `align` can already handle multiple lines, right?

Comment: an `align` block has every line numbered.  you might want two lines numbered together, instead of two numbers; `split` will accomplish that.  (there are probably other reasons, but this is a common one.)

Comment: Positioning of the equation number according to the options passed to `amsmath`.

Comment: You may  need a subalignment for some of the align equations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The equation number for `split` is placed according to the `centertags` (default) or `tbtags` options to `amsmath`. You can't obtain the same effects with `\notag`. Note that `split` keeps the same alignment point, which `aligned` can't do.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

reqno and centertags
\begin{align}
a &= b \\
\begin{split}
c &= d \\
  &= e
\end{split} \\
f &= g
\end{align}

\makeatletter\ctagsplit@false\makeatother
reqno and tbtags
\begin{align}
a &= b \\
\begin{split}
c &= d \\
  &= e
\end{split} \\
f &= g
\end{align}

\makeatletter\tagsleft@true\ctagsplit@true\makeatother
leqno and centertags
\begin{align}
a &= b \\
\begin{split}
c &= d \\
  &= e
\end{split} \\
f &= g
\end{align}

\makeatletter\tagsleft@true\ctagsplit@false\makeatother
leqno and tbtags
\begin{align}
a &= b \\
\begin{split}
c &= d \\
  &= e
\end{split} \\
f &= g
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Note how `split` maintains the outer alignment position but numbers the combined rows with a vertically centred number.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}

align, two  numbers
\begin{align}
  a&=b \nonumber\\
   &\quad + c \\
  x&=y
\end{align}

split in align, two numbers
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
  a&=b \\
   &\quad +  c
\end{split}\\
  x&=y
\end{align}


\end{document}
```